# MP3 Sound Duration 0 seconds not playing in android, error in log nullpointexception

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

Here `click21` is a `mp3` sound of duration 0 seconds, which I convert from `click21.aiff`. But when I run this, I receive an error error of type `nullpointexception`.
Can you tell me what is problem?

```
 MediaPlayer mp;
 mp =MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.click21);
    mp.start();
```

Error log

```
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.simba.silicon/com.simba.silicon.startscreen.CircleMenuScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at com.zippy.zippyapp.startscreen.CircleMenuScreen.onCreate(CircleMenuScreen.java:127)
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
03-31 11:39:56.371: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: I don't think you should be trying to create a MediaPlayer with a *drawable* as a source.  That probably would fail (it's hard to imagine how it couldn't), meaning mp is null, and you'll get a null pointer exception when you try to call a method of a null object on the next line.

Comment: Can you tell me what i use on place Mediaplayer

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you tried to pass a mp3 file for a image.
What you want to do is to create a raw folder inside your res/ folder.

Then when you call the MediaPlayer do this :

```
MediaPlayer md = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.click21);
    md.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    md.prepareAsync();
```

Comment: what is the type of error ? Can you post your log somewhere ?

Comment: i just added in question

Comment: What it is @127 ? at com.zippy.zippyapp.startscreen.CircleMenuScreen.onCreate(CircleMenuScreen.java:127)

Comment: md.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() { on 127 line

Comment: change MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click21); to MediaPlayer.create(CircleMenuScreen.this, R.raw.click21);

Comment: Or maybe it cant play the .aiff file, test a .mp3 file instead

Comment: remove the sound from the drawable folder, and create inside /res folder a folder called raw, and put your sound file inside it. It's not a drawable

Comment: Other sound file run correct but the sound with track duration 0 second not working

Comment: because it's 0 ? It's not long enough to play it

Comment: but in window or linus media player its run and i can listen click sound

Comment: @RizwanAhmed could you figure it out ?